# How to convert Multiple Dates in BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a csv file with my objects 'Company'. Each company has a date of start, a date of cessation of activity and the creation date in the System.

The two first dates format is dd/MM/yy and the last one's format is dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm.

Using BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper, I don't know how to parse the two formats of date together using xml beans. My code :

```
code 
<bean id="companyReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
       scope="step">
       <!-- Read a csv file -->
       <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
       <property name="encoding" value="${batch.company.encodage}" />
       <property name="lineMapper">
           <bean class="org.project.batch.utils.ReadEntityLineMapper">
               <!-- split it -->
               <property name="lineTokenizer">
                   <bean
                       class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                       <property name="delimiter" value="${batch.company.separator}" />
                       <property name="names"
                           value="name,dateStartActivity,dateEndActivity,dateCreation" />
                   </bean>
               </property>
               <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                   <!-- map to an object -->
                   <bean
                       class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                       <property name="targetType"
                           value="org.project.entity.company" />
                           <property name="customEditors">
                               <map>
                                   <entry key="java.util.Date">
                                       <ref bean="shortDateWithHourEditor" />
                                   </entry>
                               </map>
                           </property>
                   </bean>
               </property>
           </bean>
       </property>
   </bean>
```

My question is how to use multiple customEditors for my dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such advanced use cases where each field has its own date format (or currency format, etc), you need to create a custom line mapper. You can still (re)use a `DelimitedLineTokenizer` in your implementation to tokenize items, but the mapping part should be custom.

Comment: I'll try that ! Thank you.

Comment: I tried it, i created a customFieldSetMapper ! and it's working ! Thanks.